# Running Wall-Rated HDMI Cable Horizontally

Tags: television

I’m trying to run Wall-Rated HDMI Cable both vertically and horizontally behind the drywall. Have tried using fish tape to assist but have made zero progress because of the insulation and metal studs…anyone have success doing this? (See picture: going from a hole behind the TV to the cutout on the bottom-left). I’m able to reach the hole directly below the TV just fine. [image]

Comment: Ah ok great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Running cables horizontally through an insulated wall is... challenging. You might have to remove a strip of drywall in order to be able to hand-fish it through, then patch up the drywall. Or, use @Armand's comment-that-should-be-an-answer.

Comment: "What color would you like to change that wall to after you cut it open, do the work, and patch the drywall?" The direct route _is_ just dealing with drywall repair.

Comment: Ok, thanks for these suggestions. Thinking baseboard removal is my best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's often easy to temporarily remove the baseboard at floor level, then run your wire straight down to the floor. Then you can run it horizontally over to the stud bay of your destination and up to your destination. Any drilling or mods to run the cable horizontally down at an inch or so above floor level will be covered up by the baseboard when you put it back on.

Another option is to drill through the floor plate at the bottom of each of the 2 stud bays and run the wire horizontally in a basement or crawl space below rather than along the baseboard area of this wall.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think removing the baseboards is my best bet

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your ceiling is open-beam.  Can you see/access the top plate of that wall?  Having run many miles of low-voltage cable in office buildings with steel-stud walls full of rock wool, I've had to go vertical to avoid cutting into drywall.  I'd come up the stud bay behind the TV, out the top plate, back into the top plate, and down the other stud bay.

Comment: Ahh ok, no unfortunately I can’t access the top plate. Will have to go to the baseboard. This is a good suggestion though, will remember to check if it’s exposed for future projects